# How to print the value (users input) of this pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, esp32

I am trying to print the contents/value of a pointer "temp" when I input a single character from the keyboard but I am getting additional characters as well. Example, when I press "p" I get the following returned p��?4��?

Can someone explain what is happening and how can I modify the code to print only the character I input without the extra characters? (I am assuming the other characters are the memory address of the pointer)

Here is the example code I am trying to modify. Taken from the EspressIf github. https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/tree/4f0769d2ed/examples/bluetooth/bluedroid/ble/ble_spp_client

This function will send data to a client using BLE. There is already a driver that handles the user input from the keyboard.

```
void uart_task(void *pvParameters)
{
    uart_event_t event;
    char userInput [20];

    for (;;) {
        //Waiting for UART event.
        if (xQueueReceive(spp_uart_queue, (void * )&event, (TickType_t)portMAX_DELAY)) {
            switch (event.type) {
            //Event of UART receving data
            case UART_DATA:
                if (event.size && (is_connect == true) && (db != NULL) && ((db+SPP_IDX_SPP_DATA_RECV_VAL)->properties & (ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE_NR | ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE))) {
                    uint8_t * temp = NULL;
                    temp = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*event.size);
                    if(temp == NULL){
                        ESP_LOGE(GATTC_TAG, "malloc failed,%s L#%d\n", __func__, __LINE__);
                        break;
                    }
                    memset(temp, 0x0, event.size);
                    sprintf(userInput, "%s", temp);
                    printf("User input ="  "%s" "\n", temp);

uart_read_bytes(UART_NUM_0,temp,event.size,portMAX_DELAY);
                    esp_ble_gattc_write_char( spp_gattc_if,
                                              spp_conn_id, 
                                            (db+SPP_IDX_SPP_DATA_RECV_VAL)->attribute_handle,
                                              event.size,
                                              temp,
                                              ESP_GATT_WRITE_TYPE_RSP,
                                              ESP_GATT_AUTH_REQ_NONE);
                    free(temp);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Comment: If you only need a single character, you dont need an array, just do `char c = 'p';` If you want a string, you need an array of at least size 2, for 1 character and 1 NUL terminator.

Comment: The input can be any key on the keyboard. This issue I have is that the input from the keyboard is returned along with extra characters. I am not sure how to only return the single character from the keyboard. I did also try a larger array of 20, same results. I updated the code above. Temp is a uint8_t.

Comment: The trailing garbage you're getting is because, one way or another, you are not creating a proper null-terminated string.  All strings in C must be null-terminated, but there are many, many mistakes you can make which can cause your strings to not be null-terminated.

Comment: One great way to end up with a non-properly-null-terminated string is to use a too-small buffer, like `char userInput [1];`.  Have you fixed that yet?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I apologize for the lack of detail and info on my project, I am new to this space. I have updated my question and added the entire function I am working on. Hope it helps clarify my original question.

Comment: Ah.  Okay.  Now the problems are (1) as posted, you're trying to print the string before you read it, but more importantly (2) `uart_read_bytes` is almost certainly *not* giving you a null-terminated string.  You need to (a) set a variable `n` to the number of characters that `uart_read_bytes` actually read (perhaps its return value?) and (b) do `temp[n] = '\0';`.  (Although, the `memset` call should have taken care of that, too, so there may be something else going on.)

Answer (score 0):

User input should be **char*(string)** then convert to int. I think that is better than trying push int right away.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

const int CHAR_SIZE = 1;
    int main(){
    int charCount = 6;
    char* str = (char *) malloc(charCount * CHAR_SIZE);

    printf("Enter x: ");
    scanf("%s", str);
    //scanf("%d", $intVariable);

    int x = atoi(str); //fail = 0

    printf("User input = %d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```